# Johnsons Noise the Same in Different Resistors?

Tags: noise

Was reading about noise in The Art of Electronics and the author says:
"The most expensive and most carefully made resistor has exactly the same Johnson noise as the cheapest carbon resistor of the same resistance"

How can that be true? I think of expensive resistors as having a tighter tolerance but maybe they are assuming the same tolerance and temp response?

Comment: Why would Johnson noise depend on the type of resistor? Its thermal noise, it depends on temperature and resistance, so if those are equal it is equal.

Comment: Thanks I think I was confused

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There will be "excess noise" that depends upon the type of resistor - carbon composition resistors will have much more noise than metal-film. That is in addition to Johnson noise that is the same for every resistor.

The excess noise will usually also depend upon the DC voltage across the noise and will often have different probability characteristics, ie it will not be white noise. Commonly it will exhibit a 1/f characteristic.

The thick film resistors typically used on surface mount designs also have significant excess noise when current is flowing through them. It is not usually an issue in most designs but where low level signals are being measured may be an issue. Thin-film resistors are the preferred type for these low-level circuits.

[Current-Induced Resistor Noise](https://www.beis.de/Elektronik/ResistorCurrentNoise/CurrentInducedResistorNoise.html)